# GCP instance cannot parse fastai resource

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, fast-ai

Trying to connect to a Jupyter Notebook in the instance through the shell, however it throws an error message informing that "the resource" could not be parsed.

[image]

This is a Windows server with an Ubuntu terminal, running fastai. The Notebook is already installed and set up, and I already increased my GPU quota to 1.

Interestingly enough, the error comes up regardless of whether the instance is running or not.